# Doing a rollback - Repository integration tests

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

I want to implement integration tests of my Entity Framework driven repositories. The problem is how to rollback database state after tests are done. At the moment I'm planning to start transaction at test SetUp and roll it back at test TearDown. Are there any other solutions excepting manual database clearing?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

We do this in our integration tests while using MSTest. We use the `TransactionScope` and implement a test setup and teardown in a base class. This allows you to run all integration tests within a transaction. The base class looks much like this:

```
public class IntegrationTestsBase
{
    private TransactionScope scope;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        this.scope = new TransactionScope();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        this.scope.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: As far as I know the `TransactionScope` works with Oracle. It is specially designed for multi-server multi-vendor (two-phase commit) communication.

Comment: Ok and after doing repo.Save(someObject) in test how do you check that object was saved?

Comment: @Peri You create the TransactionScope ala "return new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions{IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted}).  That way you can see uncommitted rows :-)

Comment: @Peri: Or you simply query the database in that test. Since you're running in the same transaction, this should work. Nothing special needed.

Comment: Is it possible that some errors will be visible only after commit which we don't do in test? For example some constraint checks failing and so on. Is it database engine (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL ...) independent? And what if we are testing that our classes can read data. And they work with ReadCommited isolation level?

Comment: Yes, @Peri. Not testing the commit is a very real caveat with this approach. But YMMV. Just sayin'.

Comment: @Peri and Christoffer, never saw this behavior when using MS SQL Server. Can't speak for any other database systems.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're on the right track....

[Here's an example doing the same with Linq To SQL that you can tweek for yourself.](http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2009/09/08/automatically-roll-back-your-linq-to-sql-integration-tests.aspx)

[This link describes three options](http://graemehill.ca/unit-testing-an-entity-framework-data-access-layer-part-2-rolling-back-the-test-database):

- Transactions
- Rebuild the DB
- Use SQL Server Snapshots

The post goes on to describe that transactions while the fastest are tied to a single session and can create some real problems/restrictions.  Use if you can....

Rebuilding the DB is slow but definitely doable but using snapshots is fast and gets around the transaction restrictions.

If you have a need to have very high performance in your automated tests [try this from the same blogger](http://graemehill.ca/high-performance-database-rollback-in-automated-tests-with-sql-server).  He describes using MS Distributed Transaction Coordinator to eliminate the transactional restrictions of a single session.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with opening TransactionScope in Setup and Disposing in TearDown is that You are NOT testing the commit!

Answer (score 2):

That's probably the easiest way, the other way is to rebuild the database at SetUp.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is a transactional approach.  The link I provided contains a short walk through.  Almost every enterprise solution I've come in contact with use a transactional based approach.  Make sure to also take a look at the links on the bottom of the article which have links to Microsoft's Documentation on transactions with entity framework.  The other options listed above are compete overkill in a simple concept of cleaning up a test transaction.  Building a database or using sever snapshots are complete overkill to this issue.  TransactionScope doesn't even execute the transaction leaving an integration test unfinished.

Implement Transactions

This will create a transaction before each tests starts and rollback the transaction after each test ends.

```
[TestClass]
public class TransactionTest
{
  protected EntitiesV3 context;
  protected DbContextTransaction transaction;

  [AssemblyInitialize]
  public static void AssemblyStart(TestContext testContext)
  {
    RetryDbConfiguration.SuspendExecutionStrategy = true;
  }

  [TestInitialize]
  public void TransactionTestStart()
  {
    context = new EntitiesV3();
    transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction();
  }

  [TestCleanup]
  public void TransactionTestEnd()
  {
    transaction.Rollback();
    transaction.Dispose();
    context.Dispose();
  }

  [AssemblyCleanup]
  public static void AssemblyEnd()
  {
    RetryDbConfiguration.SuspendExecutionStrategy = false;
  }
}
```

[Great quick walk through on transactional rollback/cleanup approach](http://codethug.com/2014/08/15/cleaning-up-ef-6-tests-with-transaction-rollbacks/)