# C# Integration testing with rollback

Tags: c#, integration-testing

I try integration testing with rollback. I use SQL server. My setup, which I took from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3538035/3246527), looks like this:

```
private TransactionScope scope;

[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
    this.scope = new TransactionScope();
}

[TestCleanup]
public void TestCleanup()
{
    this.scope.Dispose();
}
```

Testing method:

```
var newUser = new UserDetailModel();
newUser.Id = 1;
newUser.Email = "test@test.cz";
newUser.FirstName = "Test";
newUser.LastName = "User";
newUser.UserName = "test.user";
await userManager.AddAsync(newUser);
```

There shouldn't be a new user in db after the test is completed, but I have new user in db even test is finished. I even tried the same method with *Database.BeginTransaction()*:

```
using (var transaction = unitOfWork.GetDbContext().Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    var newUser = new UserDetailModel();
    newUser.Id = 1;
    newUser.Email = "test@test.cz";
    newUser.FirstName = "Test";
    newUser.LastName = "User";
    newUser.UserName = "test.user";
    await userManager.AddAsync(newUser);

    transaction.Rollback();
}
```

Rollback doesn't work either.

Comment: This is not a unit test; this is an integration test. A unit test would mock out the dependency (i.e. the database).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make TransactionScope and async work properly use .NET 4.5.1. or later and You have to explicitly opt-in the transaction flow across thread continuations by specifying `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled` like this:

```
new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled)
```

Read more on the topic: https://particular.net/blog/transactionscope-and-async-await-be-one-with-the-flow