# Create stored procedure on Effort database for Unit Test

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, stored-procedures, effort

I have a function calling a stored procedure with Entity Framework :

```
public async Task<List<Entity>> GetEntity(int id)
{
       var param = new SqlParameter("@id", id);
       return await myContext.Database
           .SqlQuery<MyEntity>("[myStoredProcedure] @id", param)
           .ToListAsync();
}
```

And i would like to create a unit test for it using Effort. I already have Effort (and NMemory database) to simulate a database (based of my context), on `Initialize` for each Unit Test, like :

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
     Effort.Provider.EffortProviderConfiguration.RegisterProvider();
     EffortProviderFactory.ResetDb()
     using (var context = new MyContext("PWET"))
     {
          context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
          context.Constructeurs.Add(new Constructeur { Nom = "Zebra" });
          context.Constructeurs.Add(new Constructeur { Nom = "Joya" });
          context.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

Where `EffortProviderFactory` is :

```
public class EffortProviderFactory : IDbConnectionFactory
{
    private static DbConnection _connection;
    private readonly static object _lock = new object();

    public static void ResetDb(){
        lock (_lock){
            _connection = null;
        }
    }
    public DbConnection CreateConnection(string nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        lock (_lock){
            if (_connection == null)
                _connection = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient();
            return _connection;
        }
    }
}
```

I tested adding the stored procedure creation like that :

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
     Effort.Provider.EffortProviderConfiguration.RegisterProvider();
     EffortProviderFactory.ResetDb()
     using (var context = new MyContext("PWET"))
     {
          context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
          context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoredProcedure]
@id INT = 0
AS
BEGIN

SELECT foo
FROM bar 
WHERE foo.Id = @id

ORDER BY foo.Id;
END");
     }
}
```

But it throws an `NotSupportedException`. How can i do, and what is the best way ?

Comment: Please post entire `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoredProcedure][...]");` Probably you are using **`GO`** batch separator.

Comment: Updated ;) No GO command

Comment: Effort and T-SQL procedure together? Probably, you should replace procedure call by equivalent C# method.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov I woul prefer not. The goal is to test my stored procedure used by my code, not an equivalent in c# who can be not buggy

Comment: The only viable solution: test against a real Sql Server database. How would you mock regularity in the output of the sproc without virtually rewriting it somewhere in your test environment? (Because, needless to say, the DDL isn't gonna work, ever)

Comment: There will be no way to do unit tests a stored procedure then?

Comment: To test stored procedure you need to compile and run stored procedure. For that you need real database. Of course you can rewrite the logic of said procedure in pure C# - but then you are not testing stored procedure any more.

Comment: @GGO what you are requesting is not feasible given the limitations of the framework being used. Also given what you are trying to test, this now becomes an integration test rather than a unit test. You would need to connect to an actual database to execute and test stored procedures. The provided answer attests to that and I agree with its assessment.

Comment: @Nkosi Yeah i understood like Gert and Ivan said, but there are inconsistencies. If NMemory accepts stored procedure, there must be someone who knows how to add a stored procedure  without necessarily going through Effort. Otherwise, it is not because there is no answer to my question or that only Gert can give me a better way that needs to be downvote. I think it's a good question. I planned to accept the Gert's answer tomorrow if I dont have another way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Effort](https://github.com/tamasflamich/effort) is a file-based in-memory database provider that supplies a `DbContext` instance with a privately owned temporary database: new context, new database, no test interactions. That's the good part.

The downside, of course, is that it isn't --and never will be-- a full-fledged database engine. Therefore it will *never* support stored procedures written in any of the common SQL dialects (like t-SQL or PL-SQL). As far as Effort (i.e. NMemory) has stored procedures, it's merely a stored `IQueryable`, as is evident from the [`StoredProcedure` constructor](https://github.com/tamasflamich/nmemory/blob/master/Main/Source/NMemory/StoredProcedures/StoredProcedure%601.cs). Noting remotely related to t-SQL stored procedures.

The only way to test stored procedures in your data access layer code, which is a very good idea, is to write integration tests. There are roughly two approaches to making integration tests independent of one another:

- Create/seed a new database for each test
- Use an existing database with test cases and roll back changes after each test, [for example using TransactionScope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3538035/861716).

Integration tests are never going to be as fast as unit tests and they only *complement* unit tests, but nevertheless, in my own coding practice related to data layers they've become first-class citizens in the test suite. For me, correctness is more important than speed.

Comment: Ok i understand, however Effort is based on NMemory engine, and in the NMemory's nuget package description is written "it supports traditional database features like indexes, foreign key relations, transaction handling and isolation, stored procedures, query optimization"....
https://www.nuget.org/packages/NMemory

Comment: @GGO Supporting the Gert's answer, the [Effort FAQ](https://effort.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ) section contains the following: *"**Does it have any limitation?** Yes, it can only emulate operations that go through the Entity Framework pipeline. This follows that database specific operations cannot work (e.g: ExecuteStoreCommand). Stored procedures, views and triggers cannot be emulated too."*